# Error with an element of a struct

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I have a fast question about the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char folder_name[MAX_FOLDER_NAME];
    Email* emails[MAX_FOLDER_EMAILS];
    int size;
    int empty;
    int protected;
} Folder;
```

Why Netbeans is not recognizing the "int protected"? The program is saying "unexpected  int" and "unexpected ;".

Comment: You should tag your question with the actual programming language used. Assuming this is C++, `protected` is a language keyword and may therefore not be used as an identifier. You'd have to rename it to something else.

Comment: @mmlr sorry, that is my mistake I will tag my question with the programming language next time thank you! Also thank you for your feedback I changed the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`protected` is a keyword in C++ and is not allowed as a variable name.